# Get mean of lowest axis in a 3D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a 3D array and want to take the mean along `axis=0`. I tried to convert to a numpy array and do `arr.mean(axis=0)`, but that throws an error because the lists in `axis=2` do not have equal lengths.

To reproduce:

```
arr = [[[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6]],
       [[10,11,12,13,14], [11,12,13,14,15], [12,13,14,15,16], [13,14,15,16]],
       [[20,21,22,23,24], [21,22,23,24,25], [22,23,24,25,26], [23,24,25,26]]]

np.asarray(arr).mean(axis=0)
```

The result would look like this:

```
[[10,11,12,13,14],
 [11,12,13,14,15],
 [12,13,14,15,16],
 [13,14,15,16]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind Tensoflow, you can do this with ragged tensors.

```
>>> arr = tf.ragged.constant(arr)
>>> tf.reduce_mean(arr, axis=0).numpy()                                                             
array([array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14.]), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 15.]),
       array([12., 13., 14., 15., 16.]), array([13., 14., 15., 16.])],
      dtype=object)
```

UPD: without Tensorflow:

```
means = [list(m) for m in 
         np.apply_along_axis(
             # preventing numpy from casting to ndarray by converting 
             # to iterators and back to lists
             lambda a: (i for i in np.asarray([*a]).mean(axis=0)),
             0, arr
         )]
```

here, basically we get a 2D numpy array of lists and map it to a 1D array of iterators, which we convert back to lists. All this is to prevent numpy from making a 2D list between the steps by going into lists of means

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get tensorflow to work on my system

Answer (score 1):

```
In [272]: arr = [[[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6]], 
     ...:        [[10,11,12,13,14], [11,12,13,14,15], [12,13,14,15,16], [13,14,15,16]], 
     ...:        [[20,21,22,23,24], [21,22,23,24,25], [22,23,24,25,26], [23,24,25,26]]]              
In [273]: len(arr)                                                                                   
Out[273]: 3
In [274]: [len(a) for a in arr]                                                                      
Out[274]: [4, 4, 4]
```

Object dtype array from the lists - 2d:

```
In [275]: np.array(arr)                                                                              
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[275]: 
array([[list([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
        list([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), list([3, 4, 5, 6])],
       [list([10, 11, 12, 13, 14]), list([11, 12, 13, 14, 15]),
        list([12, 13, 14, 15, 16]), list([13, 14, 15, 16])],
       [list([20, 21, 22, 23, 24]), list([21, 22, 23, 24, 25]),
        list([22, 23, 24, 25, 26]), list([23, 24, 25, 26])]], dtype=object)
In [276]: _.shape                                                                                    
Out[276]: (3, 4)
In [277]: np.frompyfunc(len,1,1)(arr)                                                                
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[277]: 
array([[5, 5, 5, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 4]], dtype=object)
```

For a 'column' of that array, we can make a 2d array, and take a mean:

```
In [278]: np.stack(_275[:,0])                                                                        
Out[278]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
In [279]: np.mean(_)                                                                                 
Out[279]: 12.0
In [280]: np.mean(_278, axis=0)                                                                      
Out[280]: array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14.])
```

doing the same for all 'columns':

```
In [281]: [np.mean(np.stack(_275[:,i]),axis=0) for i in range(4)]                                    
Out[281]: 
[array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14.]),
 array([11., 12., 13., 14., 15.]),
 array([12., 13., 14., 15., 16.]),
 array([13., 14., 15., 16.])]
```

Does it makes sense to talk about mean on the 'lowest axis' in this case?  If we strip off the length 4 sublists, we can makes a 3d array, and take a mean:

```
In [290]: np.mean(np.array(arr,object)[:,:3].tolist(), axis=0)                                       
Out[290]: 
array([[10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15.],
       [12., 13., 14., 15., 16.]])
```